# line 26 pos 14: 'url != null': is not true

Tags: flutter

Am having an issue with reading some data from Firebase. It gives me the above-mentioned error. I checked on Icons link they have images, it becomes so fun because am only being able to read the first car in vehicle db. below is my car class as well the DataBase API.
Brands.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:gerente_loja/core/services/api.dart';
class BrandsScreens extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: Api('vehicle').getDataColletions(),
            builder: (context, snapshot){
              if (!snapshot.hasData){
                return Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                    valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
                        Colors.green),
                  ),
                );
              }
              else {
                return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                      return Container(
                        child: InkWell(
                          child: Card(
                            child: ListTile(
                              leading: AspectRatio(
                                aspectRatio: 0.8,
                                child: Image.network(
                                  snapshot.data.documents[index]['icon'],
                                  height: 500,
                                  //width: 300,
                                  fit: BoxFit.contain,
                                )
                              ),
                              title: Text(snapshot.data.documents[index]['make']),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  );
              }
            }
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Api.dart

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class Api {
  final Firestore _db = Firestore.instance;
  final String path;
  CollectionReference ref;
  Api (this.path){
    ref = _db.collection(path);
  }
  Future<QuerySnapshot> getDataColletions(){
    return ref.getDocuments();
  }
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> streamDataCollection(){
    return ref.snapshots();
  }

  Future<DocumentSnapshot> getDocumentById(String id){
    return ref.document(id).get();
  }
  Future<DocumentSnapshot>removeDocumentById(String id){
    ref.document(id).delete();
  }
  Future<void> updateDocument(Map data, String id){
    return ref.document(id).updateData(data);
  }
  Future<DocumentReference>addDocument(Map data){
    return ref.add(data);
  }
}
```

Also here is what I get in the screen.
[Mobile Phone Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vd1b9.png)

[This is the Structure of my Collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N70Vt.png)

I Can see The Information on the Query Document. However, It does not display on the Phone.
[Query Document Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nzgQ.png)

Comment: How document structure looks like? It seems that `icon` does not exist in `snapshot.data.documents[index]`. Can't you debug it?

Comment: @ClaudioRedi I just put the structure of my collection you can click on (Structure of my Collection) as well the Mobile Phone Output so that you can see what am getting on the result. I just find it weird that for the first element is getting the data correctly. However, for others is not getting anything at all

Comment: What do you see if you debug and explore `snapshot.data.documents[index]`?

Comment: @ClaudioRedi I can see the information within the snapshot.data.documents[index], however, does not display on the screen. Please have a look on the Query Document Result above.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in my DB the link to one of the fields was getting wrong. I had to visit all of them and change it.